# Customize creating account

Tags: wordpress

I have a small question, I'm using wordpress, when I'm creating an user account is it possible to add a birth date parameter ? I don't know how to use php, does a plugin exist to customize it ? 
I have search but couldn't find anything TT

Thank you for you response and sorry for my English ^^'

Answer (score 0):

This is the plugin you're want to try.  I wouldn't do this with a plugin but if you don't know PHP or other coding methods then this is probably your best option.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-meta/

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it seem like with using this plugin I can't use the wordpress role.... Is there any solution to change wordpress user creating form ? (from the background). If I try using php will it be possible ? ^^